# A medium length crossword

Tags: crosswords

[image]

> Across
>   2. weird
>   3. enchanted
>   6. thickened
>   9. short sighted
>   12. empty, open, or void
>   14. to pawn something
>   16. shady
>   17.  feeling melancholy
>   18. poem of praise
>   19. relating to the sea
>
> Down
>   1. pleasant earthy smell
>   4. to darken
>   5. obsessed about one's health
>   7. optimistic
>   8. very brief
>   10. affable
>   11. book dealer
>   12. lubricating fluid
>   13. a small invertebrate
>   15. investigating; before inquiry

Comment: Lol trying to make Sid happy :)

Comment: @North trying. crosswords happen to be one type of puzzle i can usually solve, and make. hopefully this is challenging, but not too difficult

Answer (score 1):

Answers I have so far:

Across:

9. short sighted

   > myopic

Down:

1. pleasant earthy smell

   > petrichor